# Change the wait cursor to default (auto) after the ajax call is complete using AjaxStop event (in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I ran into this problem and from some google search I realized that this is probably a bug in Chrome and Safari browsers.

When I submit a form (basically , make an ajax call) the default cursor changes to wait cursor (hourglass) and when the ajax call is complete ( response ) the cursor changes to the default type (arrow). However, this only works well in IE and FF. In Chrome, the cursor still remains to be hourglass cursor until I do something like move the cursor or have an alert etc.

I tried a solution much like the one mentioned [here](http://postpostmodern.com/instructional/global-ajax-cursor-change/) which uses the Jquery's Ajax Stop and Start event to trigger actions but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Below is my jsp/html code.

```
function SubmitForm()
{
    globalAjaxCursorChange(); 
    // some code to make Ajax call
}

function globalAjaxCursorChange()   
{  
    $("html").bind("ajaxStart", function(){  
        $(this).addClass('busy');  
    }).bind("ajaxStop", function(){  
        $(this).removeClass('busy');  
    });  
}
```

And this is my CSS code.

```css
html.busy, html.busy * {  
    cursor: wait !important;  
}
```

What am I missing or where am I wrong ? The solution as mentioned in the article seems pretty straight foward to me but doesn't work. Thanks much for any advise.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the `.bind` variants didn't work, but when I googled for "jquery bind ajaxStart", [this](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) was the first search result.

As such, with just the tiniest change (that is, changing `.bind("ajaxStart",` to `.ajaxStart(` and the same with `ajaxStop`), I got your code to work, as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Global ajax cursor change
    $("html")
        .ajaxStart(function () {
            $(this).addClass('busy');
        })
        .ajaxStop(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('busy');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As of jquery 1.9 you [should attach them to document](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#ajax-events-should-be-attached-to-document).

```
// Makes the mousecursor show busy during ajax 
// 
$( document )

   .ajaxStart( function startBusy() { $( 'html' ).addClass   ( 'busy' ) } )     
   .ajaxStop ( function stopBusy () { $( 'html' ).removeClass( 'busy' ) } )
```